# Polling issue for DB inserts

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I want to implement a Polling Service which should hit a particular table to fetch the latest records inserted from any other application or may be by direct insert query on SQL prompt. It should be listening to table for all inserts or i should hit table at every few seconds to get new records. Please help me with how to achieve it, by polling service OR listener OR multi threading.

I created a listener as below:-

```
@Component
public class SMSListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>, PostInsertEventListener{

@Autowired
SMSServiceImpl serviceImpl;

@Autowired
SendSMS sendSMS;

public SMSListener() {

}

@Override
public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
    log.debug("Entering SMSListener:onPostInsert:::::::::::::::");

    try {
        sendSMS.sendSMSes();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
     System.out.println("event: " + event);              
}}
```

and one EntityEventListenerRegistry class:-

```
 @Component
 public class EntityEventListenerRegistry {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
                        EntityEventListenerRegistry.class);

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return buildSessionFactory();
}

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory; 
}

/**
 * EventListenerRegistry:
 * http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/
 * Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-entitylisteners
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@PostConstruct
public void registerListeners(){
    logger.info("Registering event listeners::::::::::::::::::");        
    EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = ((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory.getSessionFactory()).
            getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, SMSListener.class);

}}
```

and below the entry of listener in model class:-

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ozekimessageout", schema = "dbo")
   @EntityListeners(SMSListener.class)
   public class SMSOutgoing implements Serializable
```

and application, main methods is :-

```
  @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.avaal.sms.*", exclude= 
  {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.avaal.sms.*")
  @ComponentScan
  @EnableAutoConfiguration 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws PlivoXmlException {
 SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication();
 application.addListeners(new SMSListener());
 SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

but I am getting error in running this code:-

```
 05:38:05.787 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: 
 Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: default
...]
 05:38:05.829 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - 
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh 
 attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
 resource         [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class] 
: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider 
org.hibernate.ejb.event.JpaIntegrator not found
 05:38:05.845 [main] INFO  
o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run 
your application with 'debug' enabled.
 05:38:05.845 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run 
failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.ejb.event.JpaIntegrator not found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/. What have you tried yourself? There is no attempt in your question on what you tried yourself, this is not a site that will write the code for you.

Comment: I tried all of these three options but none is working for me, I know no one will write code for me, but which approach should work for my problem statement.